# How to assign to to an uninitialized pointer variable in a function?

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to make this program legal and correct:

```c
#include <assert.h>                                                             
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             
                                                                                
#define SOME_INT 5                                                              
                                                                                
                                                                                
void assign_to_x(??) {                                                     
     ???                                                             
}                                                                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
void main(void){                                                                
    int *x;                                                                     
    assign_to_x(?);                                                            
    assert(*x == SOME_INT);                                                     
    // potential cleanup                                                                 
}
```

Initially `x` in pointing to some location such that I cannot dereference it without causing undefined behavior. So in the `assign_to_x` I cannot just put `SOME_INT` into the location it's pointing. What are my options then?

One option I see is:

```c
void assign_to_x(int **x) {                                                     
    *x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *));                                          
    **x = SOME_INT;                                                             
}                                                                               
                                                                                
                                                                                
void main(void){                                                                
    int *x;                                                                     
    assign_to_x(&x);                                                            
    assert(*x == SOME_INT);                                                     
    free(x);                                                                    
}
```

This however seems to be an overkill.

Another thing I can think of is:

```c
void assign_to_x(int **x) {
    static int y = SOME_INT;
    *x = &y;
}


void main(void){
    int *x;
    assign_to_x(&x);
    assert(*x == SOME_INT);
}
```

But is it actually valid? Is there a different, canonical option?

Comment: In the first example you should allocate space for `sizeof(int)` not `sizeof(int*)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `static int` solution satisfies your program’s needs, then the solution with that is okay. It is important to be aware that if the program is later modified so that it needs multiple instances of `*x`, say because its is redesigned to use multiple threads for some work, then the `static int` solution will break unless it is modified too.

The `malloc` solution has a bug; `sizeof(int *)` should have the size of an `int`, not the size of a pointer to an `int`.

Otherwise, the `malloc` solution is not over-engineered except that the cast is not needed in C; `*x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));` can be `*x = malloc(sizeof **x);`. This is allowed because C allows the `void *` type that `malloc` returns to be implicitly converted to `int *`. It is preferred because if a programmer accidentally fails to declare `malloc` (as by including `<stdlib.h>`), it will allow the compiler to produce a warning. (With the cast, some compilers will generate a default declaration for `malloc` with an `int` return type, due to the history of C development, and then the explicit cast will convert this `int` to `int *`. Without the cast, the compiler will issue a warning for the improper assignment of `int` to `int *`.)

It is also nicer to use `sizeof **x` rather than `sizeof(int *)` because then, if `x` is later changed to some other type, such as `double **x`, the `sizeof` does not need to be changed too; it automatically follows the type of `x`.